# How to use CSS on HTML page to put an image next to H2 tag

Tags: css

I am using a SaaS System, that I cannot put things next to each other, but I can put css and HTML, but the HTML is not part of it, it is like putting it on a field, so it does not work the way I want.

So, just to use CSS, how could I put content next to the image, like this image:

[https://s3.amazonaws.com/pf-upload-01/u-23218/1/2020-07-25/xi035qz/Section1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fv92.png)

So the Image is on the right, then how I can have CSS put the H2 and the other div's put that id next to the image, instead of under it?

Can you some show me how to do it?

I would really appreciate to learn how to do it.

My best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use: `display: flex;` in css

Comment: I searched for what you showed me and found an example, that worked. Thank you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

write your html as this

```
<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="image"> 
   //image will be here
 </div>
 <div class="text">
   // text will be here 
 </div>
</div>
```

and css should be as bellow

```
.flex-container {
  display:flex
  justify-content:space-between
  }
```

Comment: I tried it exactly that way, but it did not work. not sure why. anyhow, I got it working now though, another way.

Answer (score 0):

You just can simply put `<span>` instead of `<h2>`.
Make the font-size&weight bigger, and float the span to the image side.